# Requesting Help: Laravel Websockets Not Working With SSL Certificate

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-websockets

## Overview

This is my first time working with websockets.
The project I'm working in is using the Laravel framework, so I chose to give [Laravel Websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) (version 1.3.0) a try.

I set up a simple proof-of-concept project using this package, and in so-doing was able to get it up and running successfully.  Communication in this proof-of-concept is insecure though (ws://).

Now, I'm trying to integrate the Laravel Websockets package into a production application which is secured with SSL, and in this instance, when I try to establish a connection from the `/laravel-websockets` dashboard, I am instantly presented with an error in my browser's console `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

The network tab shows communication is being attempted securely (wss://).
It shows the proper domain name and port as well.
Because of this, I think the problem is server-side, yet I still don't know where the problem is.

I have encountered the same results in my local dev environment (Win 10/IIS/PHP7.4/Self-signed SSL Cert), as well as in a sandbox environment (Win Server 2016/IIS/PHP7.4/Let's Encrypt SSL Cert)

In case it makes any difference, in my local dev environment, I'm using the `HOSTS` file to redirect traffic from `myapp.dev.local` to `127.0.0.1`

### Relevant Parts Of My `.env`

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=XXX
PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXX
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=IHAVENEVERDONETHISBEFORE
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1


LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="C:/certificate.cer"
#LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="C:/privateKey.key"
#LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE=1234
```

When reviewing the documentation for the laravel-websockets library, I see that I need to configure the `config/websockets.php` file to point to my certificate file(s) and that they must be PEM encoded.  After doing a quick search online, it looks like `.cer`, `.crt`, `.pem` files will all fit this bill.  I have used an MMC snap-in to Export the Certificate in use as Base-64 encoded X.509 (CER), and have been pointing my environment variables to it.

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

### websockets.php

```
    /*
     * Define the optional SSL context for your WebSocket connections.
     * You can see all available options at: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php
     */
    'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

        'allow_self_signed' => true,

        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

### broadcasting.php

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

### bootstrap.js

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
console.log('Here')

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], // <-- only use ws and wss as valid transports
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it's work : 

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/879#issuecomment-1528775633